# How to read decimal numbers in csv file with spark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a file which contains numbers with decimals and when I read the csv file with spark, I get null for some columns and some few digits for other columns. I guess it has to do with the option adjustments I make during the spar.read. Here is my code

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType, DecimalType, DecimalType, StringType, StructField, 
StructType

schema = StructType([
StructField("Date", DateType(), False),
StructField("Total MV", DecimalType(16,5), False),
StructField("Total TWR", DecimalType(16,5), False),
StructField("Prod1 MV", DecimalType(16,5), False),
StructField("Prod1TWR", DecimalType(16,5), False),
StructField("Prod2 MV", DecimalType(16,5), False),
StructField("Prod2TWR", DecimalType(16,5), False),
StructField("StockAll", DecimalType(16,5), False)
])


df_mr = (spark.read
            .option("delimiter", ";")
            .option("inferSchema", True)
            .csv("here is the link of the file", loclae="sv_SE")

df_mr.schema
df = (
  spark.read
   .option("delimiter", ";")
   .schema(schema)
   .csv("here is the link to the file", locale="sv_SE")
   )
df.createOrReplaceTempView("output")
df.show()
```

The out I get is the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxBgv.png) and then when i use SQL

```
%sql
 select * from output
```

to get the table, i get the following [SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayrYi.png). I don't understand why I get null and number formats that are different from the first image. The sample data as input is [indata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zlcS.png).

Comment: hi @StochasticVolatility, please provide sample data that using as input for Dataframe

Comment: do you have headers in your csv? when you say   'select * from out'
do you mean  'select * from output?' what is df_mr used for?

Comment: @Young Yes, I mean "output". df_mr is just a dataframe which will be converted into an sql tabel and thereafter I will only use SQL syntax to manipulate data.

Comment: change `DecimalType(16,5)` to `DecimalType(20,5)` and add `("header", "true")` in df

Answer (score 0):

**I tried with your sample data**

`DecimalType(20,5)` will allow 20 digits before decimal to visible and adding `.option("header", True)`  will convert first line as header and will remove the null values which are getting created.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType, DecimalType, DecimalType, StringType, StructField, StructType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp, to_date
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schema = StructType([
StructField("Date", DateType(), False),
StructField("Total MV", DecimalType(20,5), False),
StructField("Total TWR", DecimalType(20,5), False),
StructField("Prod1 MV", DecimalType(20,5), False),
StructField("Prod1TWR", DecimalType(20,5), False),
StructField("Prod2 MV", DecimalType(20,5), False),
StructField("Prod2TWR", DecimalType(20,5), False),
StructField("StockAll", DecimalType(20,5), False)
])


df_mr = (spark.read
            .option("delimiter", ";")
            .option("header", True)
            .option("inferSchema", True)
            .csv("/FileStore/tables/samplecsvdatadeci.txt"))

df_mr.printSchema()
df_mr.show()

df = (
  spark.read
    .option("delimiter", ";")
    .option("header", True)
    .schema(schema)
    .csv("/FileStore/tables/samplecsvdatadeci.txt")
   )
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("output")
```

```
%sql
 select * from output
```

***Output***

[image]

[image]